# create ini file, write values in PHP

Tags: php, configuration, ini

I cannot find a way that easily lets me create a new file, treat it as an ini file (not php.ini or simiilar... a separate ini file for per user), and create/delete values using PHP. PHP seems to offer no easy way to create an ini file and read/write/delete values. So far, it's all just "read" - nothing about creating entries or manipulating keys/values.

Comment: when you say "per user", what do you mean?  Per use of the PHP application?

Comment: why do you need an .ini file per user? shouldn't that type of information be stored in a DB?

Comment: well, i meant that i want an ini file set for each user of the same PHP application. For example, chad.ini, jeff.ini, mary.ini, anne.ini

Comment: @netrox, I think Peter Bailey's getting at what you mean by user - the username on the host machine (the username apache's running under or whatever), or the end-user of your application (i.e. the person accessing it in a browser)?

Comment: btw - welcome to stackoverflow.com - great first question!

Comment: It's true, there are no built in functions for writing ini files, although the syntax is quite simple and it wouldn't take much to write a function to help with that. I suppose php's philosophy is that ini files are for humans to write. You might want to check out the write_ini_file function left in the comments here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: You really should be storing per user data in a database. It is faster and much more scaleable. Unless this app is for only 5 or 10 people you are really shooting yourself in the foot by not doing the work to make it database driven. heck even windows uses a database for what it used to use .ini files for (called the registry now ;) )

Comment: If must store it in a file, or other single-field string -  You may want to consider using JSON instead: [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). More flexible (booleans, integers, arrays, objects etc.) and very mobile (many languages have JSON encoders/decoders nowadays).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36997282/285594

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Found following code snippet from the comments of the PHP documentation:

```
function write_ini_file($assoc_arr, $path, $has_sections=FALSE) { 
    $content = ""; 
    if ($has_sections) { 
        foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
            $content .= "[".$key."]\n"; 
            foreach ($elem as $key2=>$elem2) { 
                if(is_array($elem2)) 
                { 
                    for($i=0;$i<count($elem2);$i++) 
                    { 
                        $content .= $key2."[] = \"".$elem2[$i]."\"\n"; 
                    } 
                } 
                else if($elem2=="") $content .= $key2." = \n"; 
                else $content .= $key2." = \"".$elem2."\"\n"; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    else { 
        foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
            if(is_array($elem)) 
            { 
                for($i=0;$i<count($elem);$i++) 
                { 
                    $content .= $key."[] = \"".$elem[$i]."\"\n"; 
                } 
            } 
            else if($elem=="") $content .= $key." = \n"; 
            else $content .= $key." = \"".$elem."\"\n"; 
        } 
    } 

    if (!$handle = fopen($path, 'w')) { 
        return false; 
    }

    $success = fwrite($handle, $content);
    fclose($handle); 

    return $success; 
}
```

Usage:

```
$sampleData = array(
                'first' => array(
                    'first-1' => 1,
                    'first-2' => 2,
                    'first-3' => 3,
                    'first-4' => 4,
                    'first-5' => 5,
                ),
                'second' => array(
                    'second-1' => 1,
                    'second-2' => 2,
                    'second-3' => 3,
                    'second-4' => 4,
                    'second-5' => 5,
                ));
write_ini_file($sampleData, './data.ini', true);
```

Good luck!

Comment: After `if (!fwrite($handle, $content)) {`, the file handle should be closed.

Comment: Also there's an error in the code when not using sections, the variable $key2 should be $key

Comment: This isn't an official solution just how your comment isn't an official comment of stack overflow.

Comment: @MartinKonecny does that imply that errors are fine in unoficial solutions?

Comment: @TomášZato No it means he shouldn't say it's official code. It could be buggy for all I know. He grabbed it from the comments section.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand context of your comment properly the first time. Thank you for making it clear for me.

Comment: Downvote. While the answer is helpful, it really would be better if the author would fix the bug in the code.

Comment: It's nice, but when we write this to file we will loose all comments.

Comment: Just wonder, if I only want to modify single value, do I have to write while file again? say I have array of ini file. $config = parse_ini_file($file, true);
$config['ABC.menu']['title'] = "New title"; ..... cant I just change one value ?

Answer (score 7):

I can't vouch for how well it works, but there's some suggestions for implementing the opposite of [`parse_ini_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) (i.e. `write_ini_file`, which isn't a standard PHP function) on the documentation page for `parse_ini_file`.

You can use `write_ini_file` to send the values to a file, `parse_ini_file` to read them back in - modify the associative array that `parse_ini_file` returns, and then write the modified array back to the file with `write_ini_file`.

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 7):

PEAR has two (unit tested) packages which do the task you are longing for:

- [Config_Lite](http://pear.php.net/package/Config_Lite) - ideal if you only want `.ini` files
- [Config](http://pear.php.net/package/Config) - reads also `.php` and `.xml` files

I'd rather use well tested code than writing my own.

Answer (score 5):

in this portion of code:

```
else { 
    foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
        if(is_array($elem)) 
        { 
            for($i=0;$i<count($elem);$i++) 
            { 
                $content .= $key2."[] = \"".$elem[$i]."\"\n"; 
            } 
        } 
        else if($elem=="") $content .= $key2." = \n"; 
        else $content .= $key2." = \"".$elem."\"\n"; 
    } 
}
```

$key2 must be replaced by $key or you would find empty keys in your .ini

Answer (score 3):

based on the above answers I wrote this class that might be useful. For PHP 5.3 but can be easily adapted for previous versions.

```
class Utils
    {
        public static function write_ini_file($assoc_arr, $path, $has_sections)
        {
            $content = '';

            if (!$handle = fopen($path, 'w'))
                return FALSE;

            self::_write_ini_file_r($content, $assoc_arr, $has_sections);

            if (!fwrite($handle, $content))
                return FALSE;

            fclose($handle);
            return TRUE;
        }

        private static function _write_ini_file_r(&$content, $assoc_arr, $has_sections)
        {
            foreach ($assoc_arr as $key => $val) {
                if (is_array($val)) {
                    if($has_sections) {
                        $content .= "[$key]\n";
                        self::_write_ini_file_r(&$content, $val, false);
                    } else {
                        foreach($val as $iKey => $iVal) {
                            if (is_int($iKey))
                                $content .= $key ."[] = $iVal\n";
                            else
                                $content .= $key ."[$iKey] = $iVal\n";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $content .= "$key = $val\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As of PHP7 this line `self::_write_ini_file_r(&$content, $val, false)` should be `self::_write_ini_file_r($content, $val, false)`

Answer (score 2):

I use this and it seems to work

```
function listINIRecursive($array_name, $indent = 0)
{
    global $str;
    foreach ($array_name as $k => $v)
    {
        if (is_array($v))
        {
            for ($i=0; $i < $indent * 5; $i++){ $str.= " "; }
            $str.= " [$k] \r\n";
            listINIRecursive($v, $indent + 1);
        }
            else
        {
            for ($i=0; $i < $indent * 5; $i++){ $str.= " "; }
            $str.= "$k = $v \r\n";
        }
    }
 }
```

it returns the text to write to an .ini file

Comment: Your snippet fails if $array_name contains a multi-dimensional array inside. That is, if the parent array has a depth of 3 or more.