# how to use php with ini files

Tags: php, ini

My php Code here

```
 <?php
    function String($word){


            $lang = parse_ini_file("../pard_language/en/language.ini");

        $key = array_search($word, $lang); 
        if(isset($key)){
        echo $key;

        }
        }


     echo String("PARD_INSTALL");
    ?>
```

my language.ini file is this

```
PARD_INSTALL = Install
PARD_USER_AGGREMENT = User Aggrement
PARD_AGREE = Agree
PARD_HOST_NAME = Host Name
PARD_DATA_BASE = Data Base
PARD_DATA_BASE_USER =  Data Base User
PARD_DATA_BASE_USER_PASS_WORD =  Data Base User Password
PARD_CONNECT = Connect
PARD_RESET = Reset
PARD_ADMIN_USER_NAME =  Admin User Name
PARD_ADMIN_USER_PASS_WORD =  Admin User Password
PARD_LOGIN = Login
```

This my above code is not working.I want to keep a ini file which contain language contain and need to get the word value using above php function.This codes not give any output.please help me to solve this ?

Comment: Done any debugging yourself? does `var_dump($lang)` show anything? If it's boolean false, then either that file's not readable, or there's a parse error. Your code also doesn't **RETURN** anything, so the `echo String()` bit is pointless.

Comment: var_dump($lang) show it nicely .I mean it is working.but when use the file derecly it's not working.is there any wrong ?

Comment: I used it as a array but it's not working see the DEMO http://codepad.org/83EajTdC

Comment: So start debugging. If you can't even TRY to fix your own code, then you shouldn't be coding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read and write to an ini file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695145/how-to-read-and-write-to-an-ini-file-with-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are searching for values not getting the key,  `parse_ini_file` would return an array of all elements so with `$lang[$word]` you should get the values you want ...

```
function String($word) {
    $lang = parse_ini_file("../pard_language/en/language.ini");
    return isset($lang[$word]) ? $lang[$word] : null ;
}
```

Now that is still a `BAD Approach` why ?

- You have to call `parse_ini_file` every time you want a which loads the files every time
- `String` is a bad name for a function
- `echo` was called twice .. 1. In the function and outside the function insted of using `return`

Here is what i would use :

```
$ini = new ArrayINI("../pard_language/en/language.ini");
echo $ini("PARD_INSTALL");
// or
echo $ini['PARD_INSTALL'];
```

Because i also extended `IteratorAggregate` i can loop all the values

```
foreach ( $ini as $k => $value ) {
    var_dump($k . " = " . $value);
}
```

Class Used

```
class ArrayINI implements ArrayAccess, IteratorAggregate {
    private $lang;

    public function __construct($ini) {
        $this->lang = parse_ini_file($ini);
    }

    function __invoke($offset) {
        return $this->offsetGet($offset);
    }

    public function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->lang);
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->lang[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->lang[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->lang[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->lang[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->lang[$offset]) ? $this->lang[$offset] : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch. Just want to add that `string` is the name of a type, and a bad choice for a function name. Also I'd replace the `null` return with something like `sprintf("[Unkown lang entry: %s]", $word)` or simply `$word`.

Comment: @Sammitch that was a temporary answer :)

Comment: @Sammitch replacing null would fail a lot of test cases ..... imagine `if(String("PARD_INSTALL")){  //kill all }`  ???

Comment: Yes, in the general case for using .ini files for app config parameters, but as far as I can tell OP is using them in this particular case to store language strings for presentation. Sending out an error string rather than a null would be preferable in this case, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$lang = parse_ini_file("../pard_language/en/language.ini");
print_r($lang);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you create a static class so you don't have to reparse the same ini file for every single key you want:

```
class IniParser {
    private static $parsedFile = null;

    public static function getValue($word) {
        if (self::$parsedFile === null) {
            self::$parsedFile = parse_ini_file("../pard_language/en/language.ini");
        }

        if (isset(self::$parsedFile[$word])) {
            return self::$parsedFile[$word];
        }

        return null;
    }
}


echo IniParser::getValue("PARD_INSTALL");
```