# How can my website store strings locally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, string

I have made a website where the user can create a design and then fill in a form. All the data is saved as strings. The website is not on a server so the only way to access it is locally, via the source files.

I was wondering; how can i save those strings locally, without a database. Basically; i hae string that need to be saved, even after the page is refreshed. Maybe the strings can be save to a text file or something.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

ps, written everything in html, css and javascript.

Comment: Why without a database?   That is what they are for.

Comment: You can use local storage: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: Havent had time, the whole things is for a market at school. Gonna fix a database later but for now i just need to save the data on my laptop

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can JavaScript save to a local file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071473/how-can-javascript-save-to-a-local-file)

Comment: Sry for dissapearing, internet died

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use localStorage, or a browser embedded database, like IndexedDB or WebSQL. These will store data inside your browser, so it wont be shared with anyone.

Comment: You can learn more in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FStorage).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can save it to a .ini file? This is easily done with PHP and the string will be stored locally. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976038/how-to-use-php-with-ini-files) thread can help you further