# PHP write to .ini file

Tags: php

Everyone, hello!

I'm currently trying to write to an .ini file from PHP, and I'm using Teoman Soygul's answer and code from here: [How to read and write to an ini file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695145/how-to-read-and-write-to-an-ini-file-with-php)

This works out great, although, when I save the data to it, it shows up strange in my .ini:

```
[Server] = ""
p_ip = "192.168.10.100"
p_port = 80
p_password = 1234
[Variable] = ""
string1_find = "Caution"
```

Most notably it also seems to see attempt to give the categories Server and Variable an empty value. Also, sometimes it saves the variable between consistency and sometimes not. How come there is no consistency here?

The code I'm using to find/post in PHP is this:

```
...
      $a=array("[Server]"=>'',"p_ip"=>$_POST['pip'],"p_port"=>$_POST['pport'], "p_password"=>$_POST['pass'],
      "[Variable]"=>'',"string1_find"=>$_POST['string1_find'],

...
```

If anyone could point me into the right direction, that would really be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using right, you should be passing a multidimentional array instead:

```
$data = array(
    'Server' => array(
        'p_ip' => '192.168.10.100',
        'p_port' => 80,
        'p_password' => 1234,
    ),
    'Variable' => array(
        'string1_find' => 'Caution'
    )
);
//now call the ini function from Soygul's answer
write_php_ini($data, 'file.ini');
```

Here is my output:

```
[Server]
p_ip = "192.168.10.100"
p_port = 80
p_password = 1234
[Variable]
string1_find = "Caution"
```

Notice that you need to create an extra array per new section and then you can start listing your custom definitions.

Comment: That indeed did the trick, thank you! Also loving the indentation, making it so much easier on the eyes.