# how to remove section from .ini file with php

Tags: php, ini, sections

With an .ini file lie this:

```
[sectionName1]
    key1=val1
    key2=val2
[sectionName2]
    key1=val1
    key2=val2
[sectionName3]
    key1=val1
    key2=val2
```

...how can the section `sectionName2` and everything it contains be removed?

Parsing the whole file as text is one way, but since PHP has `parse_ini_file`, it seems like there would be a built-in function for something like this. The `parse_ini_file` documentation does not address any special way to alter ini files.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You can use parse_ini_file that you mentioned to read the file into a multidimensional array with keys corresponding to the section names. Removing a key from an array is easy; you probably already know how to do that. And there are some ideas as to how to write the file back out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695145/how-to-read-and-write-to-an-ini-file-with-php

Comment: As far as I know, there is not a built-in function for writing the ini file back out.

Answer (score 0):

> [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) loads in the ini file specified in filename, and **returns the settings in it in an associative array**.

*(Emphasis by me)*

So if you parse the given .ini file you'll have the whole as an array which means you can do:

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini");
unset($ini_array['sectionName2']);
```