# Storing Configuration without MySQL

Tags: php, configuration, storage, flat-file

I want to be able to store website configuration without the use of mysql. I also want the user to be able to change this information from a web page. What's the best methods to do so?

Comment: Sorry about taking so long to accept an answer. Was away from my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valuable options are a [SQLite database](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php), or just a PHP file containing a [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array if you want a really simple option:

```
// reading configuration
$config = unserialize(file_get_contents('config'));

// storing configuration
file_put_contents('config', serialize($config));
```

Comment: I want to keep this project as flat-file as possible, and a serialized array is a good idea.

Comment: A SQLite database is just a flat file containing your database, but it is also more complex for such a simple requirement though!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. Any other ways you can think of doing this? I see a lot of sites making "editable settings" but I am aware of them using a MySQL database. I'm trying to keep it flat file b ecause my project only has one database table and i want to distribute it, and i don't want to have to distribute a huge sql file for the people who download it to import into their MySQL database.

Comment: If you already have a MySQL database for something else, then I would use it for storing the config as well, unless there's a very good reason to do so (and I'm not sure to understand yours!)

Comment: I just don't want to have to distribute a large .sql file with my code, I guess I was being picky.

Answer (score 2):

Storing a file is the easiest option. You could store it in plain text, XML, JSON, etc. You might want to try an ini file which can be read/written by PHP - in which case [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268378/create-ini-file-write-values-in-php) should help.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a .ini file format to store configuration. It's human readable in its raw format and fairly easy to parse via PHP ([`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)). A point to note here is that PHP (strangely) doesn't support writing to ini files natively, but if you look at the manual page for parse_ini_file you can find an user submitted example of how do it.

Altough I have not used in PHP projects, [YAML](http://www.yaml.org) (Yet Another Markup Language) seems like a good format to store configuration info (it's pretty much the default config format for rails projects). You can use the [syck](http://pecl.php.net/syck) pecl library to easily read and write stuff in the YAML format

Answer (score 1):

You could try cloud based databases if you don't have access to store data on your own server.