# How to make a CMS config file in PHP (custom)

Tags: php, content-management-system

I am making a custom CMS in PHP and I want to know what the best way would be to create a config file for it. I want it where I can change the variables from within the admin panel I am going to add. I have not messed with the filesystem functions before or any other file functions so I am not sure what would be the best approach.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `.ini` file can be structured quite well and you'll be able to update just sections of. Compared to a straight PHP configuration it can be edited with an easier syntax.

To parse the `.ini` file into a PHP array, use the function [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

Comment: ini files are more what I am looking for, thank you! I wanted it to be human-readable so I could easily change values in case I can't get into the database for whatever reason. And like you said, I can just update sections.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a human-readable config file format then look into [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/parse_ini_file). You'll need to be able to write to the file too, see: [create ini file, write values in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268378/create-ini-file-write-values-in-php). 
There's a PEAR Package [Config_Lite](http://pear.php.net/package/Config_Lite) that seems like it should work too.

If readability doesn't matter then save it to a [database](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the variables to be changeable via an admin web interface, store those variables in the database like any other [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) data.

Comment: i have always wondered if it was necessary to store/how to store into the database a single line data, like say "footer credits" and "site name". a config file is better in this situations.

Comment: @Joseph Why would you need a web interface to change the site name? It's hardly something you'd do on a regular basis.

Comment: the part of the purpose of a CMS is to make it easy for non-techy people to edit site settings as well as provide access to a lot of off-site configurations from within the admin section of the site.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea I think is to use MySQL to store the data.

However, if you cannot do that for some reasons, then I would suggest to make it an XML file and then you can get variables from [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), and such, you can view all and put their values to a form. Then, the destination PHP could easily make a string like `"<val1>".$_POST["value1"]."</val1><val2>".$_POST["value2"]."</val2>"`. Finally, it would save the file through simple file system functions, which you can learn with googling "php file write".

Or another idea is the [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/parse_ini_file) which is already mentioned.

If you don't understand something, ask. Or Google!