# Adding quotes to .ini file values PHP

Tags: php, quotes, ini

I have a .ini file as follows:

```
[playlist]
numberofentries=2
File1=http://87.230.82.17:80
Title1=(#1 - 365/1400) Example Title
Length1=-1
File2=http://87.230.56.25:80
Title2=(#2 - 370/1400) Example Title
Length1=-1
Version=2
```

I would like to know how I can programmatically read this file in, add quotes around the file and title values and then save this file again in PHP.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use escaping when writing `"` into a file, using `'\"` will be sufficient.
For [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1268642/1428773) and [reading](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) *.ini* files, I suggest you looking at the two linked resources.