# PHP - How to check if a section exists in a INI configuration file and to add it if it doesn't exist

Tags: php, config, ini

I'am using the `parse_ini_file()` function to parse my configuration file in PHP. The `process_sections` parameter is set to True because I need the sections.

```
[section 1]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
...

[section 2]
...
```

What I'd like to do is to test if a section within an existing configuration file exists and if not I want to create it, along with the keys and values taken from an array, without overriding the other sections.

I know that in python there is a boolean method that allows to check it easily: `config.has_section('my section')`, and to create sections: `config.add_section('my section')`.

I was wondering if there is something similar in PHP.

**EDIT:**

I found a simple solution but very effective. I used the `array_key_exists('my section', $my_array)` function which is similar to the python function I mentioned before and it does what I wanted. This is the simple code I have implemented

```
$config = parse_ini_file('MyConfigFile.cfg', True);

if (!array_key_exists('section 3', $config)) {
    foreach ($section_three_array as $key => $value) {
        $config['section 3'][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Then, to write back the new section (if it didn't exist) with its keys and values to the configuration file I used the function defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316873/php-array-to-a-ini-file).

Answer (score 0):

You can check a value exists using `isset()` and I recommend checking it also has a value with `empty()`. If you show some of your code we can advise on implementing those.

There's no native way to write back to the ini file, but [here is a function someone else has made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268378/create-ini-file-write-values-in-php).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that link but I prefer the way I wrote in the EDIT.