# How to edit an uploaded file in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ini

I am uploading an `.ini` file using CodeIgniter.

Once I upload the file I use PHP's INI parser and get the file contents as an array.

Now I want to edit the contents of that file. How do I do it?

My Code:

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('customer/upload/upload_ini', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        foreach ($data as $info)
        {
            $filepath = $info['file_path'];
            $filename= $info['file_name'];
        }

        $this->data['parameters'] = parse_ini_file($filepath.$filename);

        $this->data['subview'] = 'customer/upload/upload_success';
        $this->load->view('customer/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
}
```

In View I do:

```
<?php 
var_dump($parameters);
?>
<tr>
    <td>OTAID</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('OTAID', set_value('OTAID', $parameters->OTAID)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>SipUserName</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('SipUserName', set_value('SipUserName', $parameters->SipUserName)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>SipAuthName</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters->email2)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>DisplayName</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters->email2)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters->email2)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters->email2)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Domain</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters->email2)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Proxy</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters->email2)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ServerMode</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters->email2)); ?></td>
</tr>
```

From my file I get this contents:

```
array (size=9)
    'OTAD' => string '0' (length=1)
    'PName' => string '' (length=0)
    'UName' => string '' (length=0)
    'DisplayName' => string '' (length=0)
    'Password' => string '' (length=0)
    'Domain' => string '' (length=0)
    'Proxy' => string '' (length=0)
    'Port' => string '' (length=0)
    'ServerMode' => string 'Automatic' (length=9)
```

Comment: i know my view code is wrong but i dont know yet how do show a text box to insert value into the file

Comment: what error display in your page ?

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: upload/upload_success.php

Line Number: 10

Comment: @msvairam i get this error

Comment: What is  code in LINE NUMBER : 10 ?

Comment: <tr>
 
  <td>OTAID</td>
  <td><?php echo form_input('OTAID', set_value('OTAID', $parameters->OTAID)); ?></td>
 
 </tr> @msvairam

Comment: @msvairam my error got solved after doing this $parameters['OTAID']

Comment: Use $parameters['OTAD'] in view file

Comment: @msvairam how do i save the updated contents into file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104170/discussion-between-msvairam-and-rajan).

Comment: Cant you use fwrite   ??

Comment: Yes But i guess i should file_put_contents here right?

Comment: Yes you can surely...

Comment: So what should be my code @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 1):

Use this Coding

```
 <td>OTAID</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('OTAID', set_value('OTAID', $parameters->OTAID)); ?></td>

    </tr>



    <tr>

        <td>SipUserName</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('SipUserName', set_value('SipUserName', $parameters['SipUserName'])); ?></td>

    </tr>


    <tr>

        <td>SipAuthName</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters['email2'])); ?></td>

    </tr>


    <tr>


        <td>DisplayName</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters['email2'])); ?></td>
    </tr>



    <tr>


        <td>Password</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters['email2'])); ?></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>


        <td>Password</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters['email2'])); ?></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>


        <td>Domain</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters['email2'])); ?></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>


        <td>Proxy</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameter['email2'])); ?></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>


        <td>ServerMode</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('email2', set_value('email2', $parameters['email2'])); ?></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: How to save this into file?? what should be my controller code?

Answer (score 0):

As already described in comments you need to use *$parameters* in view as array because *parse_ini_file* returns one.

What kind of text box you want to generate? You are using a normal input field , do you mean a *textarea*?

How to generate an ini-file from array you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316873/php-array-to-a-ini-file). You can use *file_put_contents* to write into the file.

Comment: can you write code for my case? i did'nt understand that! Now have an array and i want to write it to the file which i opened