# How to save JSON into ini-file with php?

Tags: php, json, ini

I have a datastream as JSON, I want to parse it and want to save result in ini-file :

```
{
    "books": [{
        "id": "1",
        "date": "2017-03-12",
        "date_text": "sunday 12 march",
        "title": "title text"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "date": "2017-03-12",
        "date_text": "sunday 12 march",
        "title": "title text"
    }]
}
```

This is my sample data and I would like to know if there is a way to save it into a file no matter if it contain 1 or more "id:s" (Items)
I know how to parse the JSON but not how to save it down to a file in correct format for an ini.

Preferable format:

```
[Books 0]
id= 1
date= 2017-03-12
date_text=sunday 12 march
title= title text

[Books 1]
id"=2
date=2017-03-12
date_text=sunday 12 march
title=title text
```

Comment: what do you have tried ?

Comment: Maybe this could help : [PHP array to a .ini file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316873/php-array-to-a-ini-file/17317168#17317168)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Zend Config](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-config/intro/) for this task. Open your terminal and add zend-config to your project as dependency (assuming you already using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)):

```
composer require zendframework/zend-config
```

Now you can try following,

```
$json = <<<JSON
{
    "books": [{
        "id": "1",
        "date": "2017-03-12",
        "date_text": "sunday 12 march",
        "title": "title text"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "date": "2017-03-12",
        "date_text": "sunday 12 march",
        "title": "title text"
    }]
}
JSON;

$config = new \Zend\Config\Config(json_decode($json, true), true);
$writer = new \Zend\Config\Writer\Ini();
echo $writer->toString($config);
```

The output will be:

```
[books]
0.id = "1"
0.date = "2017-03-12"
0.date_text = "sunday 12 march"
0.title = "title text"
1.id = "2"
1.date = "2017-03-12"
1.date_text = "sunday 12 march"
1.title = "title text"
```

Your JSON format should be look like below to produce desired output you wrote in question:

```
{
    "books 0": {
        "id": "1",
        "date": "2017-03-12",
        "date_text": "sunday 12 march",
        "title": "title text"
    },
    "books 1" : {
        "id": "2",
        "date": "2017-03-12",
        "date_text": "sunday 12 march",
        "title": "title text"
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to get Zend added to Project. is there a way to know if its added/working other than phpinfo() ?

Comment: There is no relation between your project structure/dependencies and phpini() I would recommend grasping the basics first by reading & practicing more before diving into data transformation.