# Output of a multidimensional array as a grouped key=>value list

Tags: php, arrays, grouping, key-value

Given is a multidimensional array like this:

```
array(51) {
  ["ACTION"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["key1"]=>
    string(6) "Item 1"
    ["key2"]=>
    string(6) "Item 2"
    ["key3"]=>
    string(6) "Item 3"
    ["key4"]=>
    string(6) "Item 4"
  }
 ["ADMIN"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key1"]=>
    string(6) "Item 1"
    ["key2"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["subkey1"]=>
      string(6) "Item 1"
      ["subkey2"]=>
      string(6) "Item 2"
    }
  }
```

I would like to output this array as a grouped list of key/value pairs like this:

```
[ACTION]
key1=Item 1
key2=Item 2
key3=Item 3
key4=Item 4

[ADMIN]
key1=Item 1

[ADMIN.key2]
subkey1=Item 1
subkey2=Item 2
```

I tried many ways but can't get the grouping to work. Any help is highly appreciated.

For example: I tried to "foreach" through the array, output the key and then key pairs values in case the value was a string. But as the array is sorted alphabetically (key), there could be a 3D array followed by a 2D entry and the [HEADER] do not relate to the correct group.

Comment: Please share some examples of your "many ways" and explain the issue you're having with them. You'll also need to explain the logic behind the expected output.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? if possible, post your attempts. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert array to an .ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316873/convert-array-to-an-ini-file)

Comment: Provide a [mre] of the issue please including your attempt so far and the specific problem encountered ("can't get it to work" isn't a useful problem description, and "Any help is appreciated" isn't a meaningful question), as per the [ask] guide. Also indicate if you researched any other possible solutions. You can [edit] your question. Thanks.