# Convert PHP multidimensional array to JavaScript notation

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am looking for an efficient and clean function to convert PHP multidimensional arrays to javascript notation definitions. For example:

```
$settings = array(
    "customer" => array(
        "first_name" => "John",
        "last_name" => "Doe",
        "company" => array(
            "name" => "Foobar Inc",
            "address" => "123 Main Street"
        )
    )
)
```

Should translate into:

```
echo 'window.customer.first_name = "John"';
echo 'window.customer.last_name = "Doe"';
echo 'window.customer.company.name = "Foobar Inc"';
echo 'window.customer.company.address = "123 Main Street"';
```

Comment: Did you try searching for this?

Comment: See updated, it is not as simple as `json_encode()`.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about why this approach is necessary over `json_encode`?

Comment: What you're trying to do is a terrible idea and makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

```
$json = json_encode($settings);
```

**Example:**

```
$settings = array(
    "customer" => array(
        "first_name" => "John",
        "last_name" => "Doe",
        "company" => array(
            "name" => "Foobar Inc",
            "address" => "123 Main Street"
        )
    )
);
        
echo json_encode($settings);
```

**Output**:

```
{"customer":{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","company":{"name":"Foobar Inc","address":"123 Main Street"}}}
```

Comment: @justin I think you will find it works like: `var somevar = <?php echo json_encode($settings);?>;alert(somevar.customer.first_name);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to generate an .ini file. I'd say you could write a simple recursive function that, given a base string to use as the start of the property name, would then generate a line of output for its value - or a sequence of lines, recursively calling itself, if the value is an array.

Another approach is given here: [create ini file, write values in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268378/create-ini-file-write-values-in-php)