# Write to INI file from PHP with keeping #comment lines

Tags: php, ini

I am using this [PHP Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2833-PHP-Read-and-write-INI-configuration-files.html) to write ini files.

I use below code to update ini file;

```
<?php
include("class.iniparser.php");
$cfg = new iniParser("config.ini");
$cfg->setValue("Tool","version", "0.9beta");
$cfg->save();
?>
```

config.ini as below;

```
[Tool]
name = mein kleiner Parser
version = 0.9alpha
lastmodified = 2006-01-16
```

When I have a comment line (ex: #company = example.com), it will automatically delete it.

I want to update config.ini file without deleting comment lines
Is there a way to achieve it?

I have tried [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1268642/2979342),
[Config_Lite](https://github.com/pear/Config_Lite),
[Piwik/Ini](https://github.com/piwik/component-ini) and [PHP INI Read and Write Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8119-PHP-Read-and-write-configuration-values-in-INI-files.html#download)

**All are giving the same result**

Appreciate your support

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party - I had the same issue and added code to one of the Piwik/component-ini that adds this functionality.

You can see the changed file [here](https://github.com/piwik/component-ini/pull/5/files). Just add the lines to your IniWriter.php and you're all set.